# My do while loop in java only runs once even when condition given satisfies it

Tags: java

My loop only runs once.

This code is suppose to take home team name, away team name, home team score, away team score and store it. It should only exit the loop when entered "EXIT". But the loop only runs once. The exit part works though. I am new to java so sorry if its just a small mistake.

I haven't handled any exceptions yet so the code is incomplete.

```
    String[] ht_name = new String[9999];
    String[] at_name = new String[9999];
    int[] ht_score = new int[9999];
    int[] at_score = new int[9999];
    Scanner scanint = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanstr = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i=0;
            //do while loop starts
    do {

        System.out.println("Enter Home team name: ");

        ht_name[i] = scanstr.nextLine();

            if(!ht_name[i].equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Away team name: ");
                at_name[i] = scanstr.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Home team score: ");
                ht_score[i] = scanint.nextInt();


                System.out.println("Enter Away team score: ");
                at_score[i] = scanint.nextInt();

                i++;
            }

        } while (!ht_name[i].equalsIgnoreCase("exit"));
       //do while loop ends
    }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code gives you `NullPointerException`, because you increment `i` variable and right after that take a value at `i` index from `ht_name` array, which equals null.

Your code should probably look like this:

```
        String[] ht_name = new String[9999];
        String[] at_name = new String[9999];
        int[] ht_score = new int[9999];
        int[] at_score = new int[9999];
        Scanner scanint = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanstr = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i=0;
                //do while loop starts
        do {

            System.out.println("Enter Home team name: ");

            ht_name[i] = scanstr.nextLine();

                if(!ht_name[i].equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter Away team name: ");
                    at_name[i] = scanstr.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter Home team score: ");
                    ht_score[i] = scanint.nextInt();


                    System.out.println("Enter Away team score: ");
                    at_score[i] = scanint.nextInt();

                    i++;
                } else {
                    break; //this statement exits the loop each time when 'exit' is typed in 
                }

            } while (true); //while (true) gives you infinite loop. So this loop is broken only when 'exit' is typed in
           //do while loop ends
```

Comment: Good answer. I would suggest adding just a little bit of detail on what you've changed. Perhaps the OP is not familiar with the `break;` statement or what it does.

Comment: @Bishant: index i is incremented before while loop condition is checked, so there is no element  at i++; but at i.

Comment: The program works fine and thank you.But, I don't understand how this program works. When the value of i is zero at first, suppose i entered "exit" at first, the value of i doesnot increase because it doesn't enter if statement. The while statement should compare it to [i-1] that mean [0-1] which is -1. But how does the program still exit?

Comment: @BishantBhattarai, actually, you do not even need this check in the while loop. The program will exit each time when 'exit' entered for "Enter Home team name: " request. This happens because of the 'break' statement which is commented in the code above. So the logic is simple: if 'exit' is typed, the loop is broken and the program exits. Otherwise, the program starts requesting for other parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Your index calculation error,
The last line of code should look like this:

```
while (!ht_name[i-1].equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your while logic. You are checking the value for an index that does not quite exist yet. Remember you already incremented. Think about it this way:

- User inputs a string
- You check whether the string is equal to "exit"
- If it does, you perform an operation **and then increment your counter**
- In your while loop, you then check whether the element **in the previous index** was "exit". If it was, you stop the loop.

As you can see, your mistake was in the final step. You were supposed to check the element in the previous index and not the one in the current index. Simply change the `while` condition to this:

```
while (!ht_name[i-1].equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding.